# Disabling links in android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview, hyperlink

First, I am quite green in the world of programming, so forgive me if my question lacks clearance in any part.
I am currently trying to make an app which requires links cannot be executed in the WebView - or in another browser for that sake. I have managed to put the following two links, [In Android Webview, am I able to modify a webpage's DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219074/in-android-webview-am-i-able-to-modify-a-webpages-dom) and [Titanium Appcelerator Quickie: Disable links in Webview](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/2847924695/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-disable-links-in-webview), together and create the following working code:

```
private class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {       
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<a.*href=/gi,'<a href=\"#\" _url=');");       
    }
}
```

The snippet above is placed before the onCreate-method and is referenced in the onCreate-method like this:

```
    viewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_engine);
    viewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    viewer.loadUrl(content);
```

Now, the code works... But only after the requested webpage has been loaded a second time. The first time I execute the WebView, example.com has all its links intact, clickable and executedable. Using the backbutton, exiting the WebView and entering it again renders all the links disabled by changing

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#" _url="http://www.example.com">link</a>
```

Now, I a theory which I am not at all sure about (I am no programmer). I believe the JavaScript is executed to slow, which results in the links-manipulation never happening. That is why it works the second time working instead with with cache. I got those thought from reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949963/disabling-caching-cookies-and-everything-else-in-a-webview). However I have no idea how to correct it.

So my question goes: How can I make sure that none of the links of the displayed website can ever be used? Is there a way to make manipulation happen before the site is displayed?

Thanks for your time and effort. This is truly an amazing community ;)

- Krede

Comment: Try remove `view.loadUrl(url);` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, it should say embedded browser that you handled that link, but you do nothing, no navigation, no `loadUrl`.

Comment: I removed the line, but the problem with the first load remained. As LAS_VEGAS pointed out, I had a faulty reference. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is wrong:

```
viewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I guess you mean this instead:

```
viewer.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
```

This explains why urls are not disabled at 1st load. But I don't understand why they are disabled 2nd time.

Additionally, I think you should remove this:

```
view.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Update: Adding the `view.reload();` resulted in a reload-loop. Editing  the reference and removing `view.loadUrl(url);` was a succes.

Comment: great it worked! I removed my suggestion regarding `view.reload()`.