# How to disable Caching, Autofill and History in Webview

Tags: android

In my android app, webview is used to open up a web page. The webpage has a login page and search website box. I can see the values being searched and login/ password info is being pre-populated when someone revisit the site using app. How Can this be avoided?

Comment: see this maybe helpful : [Disabling caching, cookies and everything else in a WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949963/disabling-caching-cookies-and-everything-else-in-a-webview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was able to stop autofill of forms and login information save using

```
myWebView.clearFormData();
myWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
myWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```